# Extract multiple values between delimiters

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a column with values of processed data elements for one activity which goes like:

> [Data subject: Information type] Data element

So if either an information type or a data subject is different, it's written as a separate data segment, with semicolon as a delimiter.

I need to extract all the unique values of data subjects (between "[" and ":") and information types (between ": " and "]") from one cell (one set of values). Information types should be separated by a line break (can't show it in this table so I'll write (linebreak))

| Data Subjects & Personal Data | Categories of persons whose data will be processed by Atos (desired outcome) | Category of personal data processed (desired outcome) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [(New/Ex) Employees: Contact Information] Phone Numbers,Personal Email,Home Address,Contact Details,Professional Email,Emergency Contact Details; [(New/Ex) Employees: Employment Information] Workforce Management details,Contract details | (New/Ex) Employees | Contact Information (linebreak) Employment Information |
| [Business partners: Contact Information] Professional Email; [Business partners: Personal Identification] Last Name,First Name; [Customers/Clients: Contact Information] Professional Email; [Visitors: Health Information] Blood type | Business partners; Customers/Clients; Visitors | Contact Information (linebreak) Personal Identification (linebreak) Health Information |

Comment: please include your sample data in editable format. Also please add desired output. Without those it's very difficult to help

Comment: @MátéJuhász sorry, I didnt' work before - I guess because there was too much data in one cell, but I shortened it now so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the M code to make your conversion:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "newCol", each [#"Data Subjects & Personal Data"]),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {{"newCol", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "newCol"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"newCol", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "persons", each Text.Replace( Text.Split( Text.Trim([newCol]),":"){0},"[","")),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "data", each Text.Trim( Text.Split( Text.Split([newCol],":"){1},"]"){0})),
    PersonalCategory = Table.Distinct( Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Data Subjects & Personal Data","persons"})),
    PersonalCombined = Table.Group(PersonalCategory,"Data Subjects & Personal Data",{"Personal Category",each Text.Combine([persons],"; ")}),
    DataCategory = Table.Distinct( Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Data Subjects & Personal Data","data"})),
    DataCombined = Table.Group(DataCategory,"Data Subjects & Personal Data",{"Data Category",each Text.Combine([data],Character.FromNumber(10))}),
    withPersonal = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Data Subjects & Personal Data"},PersonalCombined,{"Data Subjects & Personal Data"}, "personal",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    PersonalExpanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(withPersonal, "personal",{"Personal Category"}),
    withData = Table.NestedJoin(PersonalExpanded,{"Data Subjects & Personal Data"},DataCombined,{"Data Subjects & Personal Data"},"data",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(withData, "data", {"Data Category"}, {"Data Category"})
in
    #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Got this error: "Expression.Error: The field 'newCol' of the record wasn't found." for the "Added Custom1" action.

Comment: I changed "newCol" to "TEST" and for some reason it worked, but I have a different issue now: 
Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.
Details:
    [List]

I suppose it's because I have other columns in my table as well (that I didn't mention in my first message) - how should the code be changed then? I suppose the list should be created separately?

Comment: It appears at this step: = Table.Group(DataCategory,"Data Subjects & Personal Data",{"Data Category",each Text.Combine([data],Character.FromNumber(10))}) ... However if I click "Go To Error", it switches to this line: = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "data", each Text.Trim( Text.Split( Text.Split([TEST],":"){1},"]"){0}))